Direct link to O365 email takes me to inbox
I have a powerautomate workflow that pulls the link from a flagged email and other details into my tasks app. Pretty simple! One of the pieces of that workflow is a copy of the email ID in a link (so that I can just navigate back to that email from the open task). Problem is that the link only ever takes me to my inbox. Even when on the outlook.office.com if I copy/paste the web address of an email I get taken back to the inbox. This makes me think the issue lies w/O365 and not me.
Regardless, code attached.
Step 1:
{
  "type": "SetVariable",
  "inputs": {
    "name": "Encode",
    "value": "@{replace(encodeUriComponent(triggerOutputs()?['body/conversationId']),'_','%2B')\r\n}"
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "Initialize_variable": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  }
}

Step 2:
{
  "type": "OpenApiConnection",
  "inputs": {
    "parameters": {
      "id": "@outputs('Create_a_task')?['body/id']",
      "body/description": "Subject: @{triggerOutputs()?['body/subject']}\nFrom: @{triggerOutputs()?['body/from']}\nBody: \n@{triggerOutputs()?['body/bodyPreview']}\n\nEmail: \n@{concat('https://outlook.office.com/mail/id/',variables('Encode'))}"
    },
    "host": {
      "apiId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_planner",
      "connection": "shared_planner",
      "operationId": "UpdateTaskDetails_V2"
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "Set_variable": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  }
}

I would expect when I copy & paste the hyperlink from an email to get taken back to that location with out edge or o365 truncating the address to the inbox.
